# Where is menu settings for node types stored in database

Tags: database

I looked in all tables to see where Drupal stores menu settings (including which menus should be available to a content type) for node types, but can't find it anywhere. We have a lot of content types on a multi site instance, and we're trying to enable menu for a content type directly in the database.

Thanks!

Comment: Which Drupal version are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

That data is in a number of different variables in the `variable` table.

Specifically for menu options, you'll find it in a var named `menu_options_CONTENT_TYPE` (e.g. `menu_options_article` for an "article" type). For the menu parent it's `menu_parent_article`, and so on.

Above assumes Drupal 7, it'll be different for 8.